# CentOS machine keeps "losing" active directory membership

Tags: centos, cron, active-directory, domain

All of our CentOS 6 machines have been joined to our active directory domain.  Each of these machines eventually "loses" their domain membership, which breaks authentication for AD users.

I created a simple shell script to force a domain join every five hours (using cron).  The script is seems to be running without error, but machines STILL lose their domain membership.

Any suggestions?

Here's the script (with password obscured)

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/net join -w MCKISSOCKLP -S MCKISSOCKLPDC1.MCKISSOCKLP.LOCAL \
    -U Administrator%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Which logs do you mean?

Comment: I'd start with `/var/log/messages`, and do a `ls -lr /var/log/` and see what files are towards the bottom, these are the ones that have activity in them. Also if you have `/var/log/samba` I'd look in there as well. The `net` command is part of Samba.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the kerberos keytab file:

```
net ads join createupn=host/$(hostname -f)@ADIRE.DOMAIN.CO.UK -U priviledged_user
net ads keytab create
net ads keytab add host/$(hostname -f)@ADIRE.DOMAIN.CO.UK
```

Then use the keytab file in your `samba` configuration:

```
$ grep -i keytab /etc/samba/smb.conf
    kerberos method = secrets and keytab
```